# In typescript,what does if(item.some((item) => !item.available) mean?

Tags: javascript, typescript

What does `if(item.some((item) => !item.available))` mean?

I was going through random code and noticed something like

```
if(item.some((item) => !item.available){
}
```

what does it mean?

```
if(item.some((item) => !item.available){

statements

}
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)?

Comment: if *some* item is *not* available ...

Answer (score 1):

That is not really typescript. There you have the [some() function from arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.
>
> Note: This method returns false for any condition put on an empty array.

I think you wanted to write item**s** So you are saying:

**If one of the item in items has a falsy value in their `available` property then run the statements.**

Answer (score 0):

`some()` is a JS built-in method on arrays that checks if any of the elements in an array pass a test (provided as a function). More info [W3Schools Array.some()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_some.asp). It returns true if any element in the array passes the condition specified by the function.

In your case, its actually checking if any of the item is **Not Available** among items, then do something.